# SELECT returning multiple rows as string

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, string-aggregation

I have a table:

Contracts:

```
contractid | contract name
"1" | "MAG:001"
"2" | "MAG:002"
```

-- and --

Devices:

```
devid | serialnum | fk_contractid
10 | 1234 | 1
11 | 5678 | 1
12 | 4321 | 2
13 | 8765 | 2
```

**devices.fk_contractid = contracts.contractid**

I need to make select which will give result:

```
"MAG:001" | 1234, 5678
"MAG:002" | 4321, 8765
```

How can that be done in PL-SQL?

Comment: Does the column 'contract name' really have a space in it, btw? :)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming 11g (when `listagg` was introduced):

```
  select    CONTRACT_NAME
         || '|'
         || LISTAGG(D.SERIALNUM, ',') within group (order by CONTRACTID)
    from CONTRACTS C join DEVICES D on D.FK_CONTRACTID = C.CONTRACTID
group by CONTRACT_NAME
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have 10g instead of 11g, there's a hidden function that's similar to LISTAGG.

WMSYS.WM_CONCAT

```
SELECT Contracts.contract_name
     , WMSYS.WM_CONCAT(Devices.serialnum)
  FROM Contracts, Devices
 WHERE Contracts.contractid = Devices.fk_contractid
 GROUP BY Contracts.contract_name;
```

WM_CONCAT does not let you sort.

You can also create your own function like this:

```
FUNCTION concat_serialnum(the_contract Contracts.contractid%TYPE)
 RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  return_value VARCHAR2(4000);
  CURSOR serials_cur IS
    SELECT serialnum
      FROM Devices
      WHERE contractid = the_contract
      ORDER BY serialnum;
BEGIN
  FOR serials_rec IN serials_cur LOOP
    return_value := return_value || ', ' || serials_rec.serialnum;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN LTRIM(return_value, ', ');
END concat_serialnum;
```

You should add code to handle the 4,000 character limit.

Your query would now be

```
SELECT contract_name
     , concat_serialnum(contractid)
  from Contracts;
```

Comment: +1, but you shouldn't need to specify the schema when using `wm_concat`. I **believe** there's a public synonym on it like all the `dbms_...` functions.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
SELECT '"' || c.contract_name || '"'
...
FROM contracts c INNER JOIN devices d ON d.fk_contractid = c.contractid
```

Add in the columns you need - using the double bar (I seem to recall) to concatenate strings.

You'll need to experiment to see how to get a quote mark - either supply it in single quotes, or in double quotes with the quote mark escaped in some way.

Comment: Bah, I just noticed you want multiple rows in the same string. There should be multiple-row functions in the Oracle docs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using 11g and can't use @John Doyle's solution, then you can create your own [aggregate function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96595/dci11agg.htm).

If you're not afraid of performance issues then you can try to use xmlagg as an aggregate function and then format it, ie:

```
select contract_name,
       rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement(e, serialnum || ',')).extract('//text()')) as serialnums
  from contracts, devices
 where contractId = fk_contractid
 group by contract_name
```

(didn't check it)