# Join multiple rows into a string

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, string-aggregation

I have 2 tables in Oracle: table1 and table2 (we have a very unimaginative DBA!)

table1 has column id (and a few others).

table2 has columns id, table1id and code. table1id is a foreign key to table1.

Usually there is 1 table2 row for each table1 row, but sometimes there are 2 table2 rows for a table1 row, and very occasionally 3.

What I need is a single 'code' value for each table1 row. If there is more than one coresponding table2 row, I need a concatenated string of all values returned, so the result might look like this:

```
table1.id     code
1             a
2             b
3             a b
4             a b c
```

Any idea how this can be achieved?
If it were SQL Server I'd write a function, although this would be slower than I would like.
However I'm not as hot in Oracle as I am in SQL Server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SELECT returning multiple rows as string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9359033/select-returning-multiple-rows-as-string)

Comment: Would be except that solution isn't available to me as our db version is only 10g.

Comment: That thread contains alternate solutions, including the WM_CONCAT alternative which is also mentioned in the answer you accepted.  So, yes, it +is+ a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not specify what version of Oracle but. If you are using Oracle 11g, then you can use the [`LISTAGG()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions087.htm) function:

```
select t1.id,
    listagg(t2.code, ' ') within group(order by t1.id) code
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
    on t1.id = t2.id
group by t1.id
```

If you are using Oracle 10g then you can use `WM_CONCAT`:

```
select t1.id,
    WM_CONCAT(t2.code) code
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
    on t1.id = t2.id
group by t1.id
```

Comment: why second sql gives me `ORA-00979: "not a GROUP BY expression"`? Exactly same as your second sql. Is this a bug of 10g..?

Comment: @Deckard I'm not sure why you'd be getting that error.

Answer (score 1):

@bluefeet has the correct solution, but if you are in 10g and don't want to use WM_CONCAT for some reason(for exemple, it's not documented), there is another one:

```
select t1.id, 
   RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(e,code,',').EXTRACT('//text()')),',') code 
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 
   on t1.id = t2.id
group by t1.id
```